# How to change the default behaviour of the Page.bringToFront() function of Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer project that has to run in non-headless mode.

There are two browser pages in total and I need to switch pages constantly, so I use the page.bringToFront() method to achieve this, but one problem is that I can't do anything else with headless=false, because chromium will always pops up. My question is how do I fix this problem? That is, how to disable chromium from popping up when page.bringToFront() is executed with headless=false.

For some reason I cant use headless mode, so I know simple headless=true would fix that problem but in my case I cant use that mode.
Thanks you all.

Comment: Can you share [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code? Why can't you run in headless mode? If due to site you could use a plugin like **puppeteer-extra**, **puppeteer-extra-stealth**, and **puppeteer-extra-anonymize-ua** that bypass checks for headless.

Comment: @idchi I fixed this problem by using the new mode of chromium `new`. Thanks for your reply.